# flutter Custom circular view

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Could anyone lead me in the right direction to build something like the following image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvqko.gif

Comment: take a look at this post: https://medium.com/flutter-io/perspective-on-flutter-6f832f4d912e

Comment: Please check Mat channel on YouTube called "Fluttery" he is doing something like that:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtWyVkPpb8An90SNDTNF0Pg

Comment: @AhmedSaied Sadly "Fluttery" has gone offline. Do you have the  git repo cloned? Or the youtube videos? It would be very helpful.